# F# read words in files to string

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I'm new to F# and I need some help.

Here is the general idea (there is more but I need help with this first): Read all txt files from specific directory, read all the words from the files and save them (for example in a seq so no newlines, special characters, etc).

I still need to be able to determine from where the words are coming so this would be a Java example `String[][] book = ["Alice in Wonderland", ["my", "name", "is", ...]]`. All the words also need to be in small caps.

This is a pure functional programming assignment so I'm not allowed to mutate anything.

Comment: I assume this is an assignment? Good places to start would be: `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles`, `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` and something like `type Book = Book of string*string list` to represent a book

Comment: @FuleSnabel Yes, this is an assignment. First I had to create a Java version and now I need to create a F# equivalent. I managed to get absolute file paths for all the files and now I need to read them but I don't know how to work with sequences here. `Seq.iter (fun i -> printfn "%s" i) seqAllFiles`. This is my list but now I don't know how to use it. Any good tutorial would be appreciated.

Comment: @Adrian Z., After with read all files, your must split string to array. For this use method Split: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Split(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Adrian Z. can you please update your question with the code you have so far? It will be vastly easier to plug the holes than to write the whole assignment from scratch for you.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin this is just a small function within the assignment and because I'm new to this syntax I need some translation. I'll do that for you in a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is simple

```
open System
open System.IO

let readFile path =
    let text = File.ReadAllText(path)
    text.Split(' ')    

let readTheFiles path =
    let files = Directory.GetFiles(path)
    files |> Array.map(fun(f) -> f, readFile f)

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let result = readTheFiles @"C:\Users\Michal\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\books"
    0
```

I hope its clear.

Note that you may change the arguments of the split to an array (of chars) for example

```
text.Split([|' '; '\n'|])
```

You can also filter the output of the split so that empty words aren't allowed.

Currently words can also repeat.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna check it out and I'll come back with the result.

Comment: I finally am able to continue this. Sorry for the wait. Isn't the Split mutating the text variable?

Comment: If you are asking if the "text" is changing/mutating, no the text stays the same. Split returns a **new** collection.

Comment: Yes that was what I was asking. I did it a bit different right now. I'll post that later.